# How to convert a date to string then split it into 4 parts using Pentaho Kettle

Tags: pentaho, olap, kettle

I have a table that contains a column named `time_created` representing a date: `2014-02-19 23:49:59.998557`. Now I need to generate a new table that consists of `year`, `month`, `day` and `quarter` columns.(For analysis purpose).

For example, `2014-02-19 23:49:59.998557` should be converted to:

year| month | day | quarter

2014 | 2 | 19 | Q1

How can I do that using Kettle? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a calculator step to generate the four fields you need (year, month,..). For each field use your timestamp as *Field A* and choose the appropriate calculation (e.g. Year of date A).
You will need to work around the quarter field to prepend a Q (calculation = set field to constant value A ). You can do this in the same calculator step, using the *remove* feature to get rid of your *Q* field.

Comment: Wow, quite amazing! Kettle is such a powerful tool!

Answer (score 2):

Or use the select values step.. this can make copies of fields then you simply specify the format mask for the date to string conversion in the meta tab. Potentially more flexible too..